# How to debug jsoncpp in eclipse

Tags: c++, debugging, eclipse-cdt, jsoncpp

I'm using jsoncpp library in my cpp project on eclipse IDE, and I'm using a lot of Json::Value objects in my application.
When debugging my program, I can't see the real content of the Json::Value objects on the watch window, I can only see some info on the object (such as minInt, maxInt...).

When I put object.toStyledString() in the watch, I can see a part of the real content but not the whole thing.

I know that there's a [debug helper for Visual Studio](http://blog.yastrebkov.com/2017/04/jsoncpp-debug-helper-for-visual-studio.html) for this, but nothing for eclipse.

Any Idea?

PS: I have an old Eclipse (Kepler), "Max Length" option on the Expressions/Variables windows doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Json::Value root;
//...

std::string strJson = root.toStyledString();
std::cout << strJson << std::endl;
```

Comment: yes,but as I mentioned, I'm using a lots fo them, it's very painfull to modify the code in each instance of a Json::Value for debug.

Comment: This answer could be improved by pointing out how it addresses the problem presented by the asker.